# Classic ASP - Insert SQL Statements - Which is better?

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic

I have an insert that does not take any parameters.

which is a better way of doing things?

```
Set writeConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Call OpenConnect(writeConn)     

        Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        objCommand.ActiveConnection = writeConn
        objCommand.CommandText = insstmt
        objCommand.Execute()
         writeConn.Close()
```

or

```
Set writeConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Call OpenConnect(writeConn)     


        writeConn.Execute(InsStmt)
        writeConn.Close()
```

they seen to be doing the same thing...thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent. I would recommend you do it like this:

```
writeConn.Execute InsStmt,,adCmdText + adExecuteNoRecords
```

The adExecuteNoRecords parameter indicates that no data will be returned and avoids the creation of an (empty) recordset.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524771%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more info.